# Word for a person who demands in "supply & demand" context

Tags: word-request, terminology

In economics and similar subjects, we have the term "supply & demand".
The word for the person (or company) who supplies is "supplier". What's the word for the person who demands?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on context. What is the relationship between the "supplier" and the "demander"? What does the "supplier" supply, goods or services or something else?
A **manufacturer** could have a **wholesaler or a customer or a buyer** depending on their business model
A **wholesaler** could have a **retailer**
A **retailer** could have a **customer**
A **professional such as a lawyer** could have a **client**
A **Doctor** could have a **patient**
And so on. I'd be slightly cautious about using **buyer** as it has different meanings depending on the situation. A buyer could be a customer in a shop, but it is also a job title in, say, a wholesaler for someone who negotiates deals with manufacturers.
There is also **factor** "a company or person that sells goods produced by another company using their own name, usually for payment" [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/factor). Not very common, but interesting.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of supply and demand it wouldn't be incorrect to use *[demander](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/demander)*, but it would be more idiomatic to use ***[customer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/customer)***.

> A patron, a client; one who purchases or receives a product or service from a business or merchant, or intends to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with **'buyer'** as opposed to 'seller' (or 'supplier').

> One who buys, a purchaser. - *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/25487?redirectedFrom=buyer#eid)*

Here is a usage in a supply & demand context:

> In any market transaction between a seller and a buyer, the price of the good or service is determined by supply and demand in a market. Supply and demand are in turn determined by technology and the conditions under which people operate.
>
> *[imf.org](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/fandd/basics/suppdem.htm)* - *Supply and Demand: Why Markets Tick*

The context is "supply & demand" and the usual general terms are "buyer" and "seller" if there isn't a specific context. These are the terms used in many economy related articles/books about supply & demand. Here is another usage:

> The buyers as a group determine the demand for the product, and the sellers as a group determine the supply of the product.
>
> *[baripedia.org](https://baripedia.org/wiki/Supply_and_demand:_How_markets_work)* - *Supply and demand: How markets work*